# How to elegantly solve $\left(x^2-\frac1{x^2}\right)^2+2\left(x+\frac1{x}\right)^2 = 2024$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots, radicals

> Find all values of $x$ such that
> $$\left(x^2-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)^2\:+\:2\,\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^2 \:=\: 2024$$

I arrived at the solutions $\,x=\pm \sqrt{22 \pm \sqrt{483}}$, $\,\pm \sqrt{-23 \pm 4 \sqrt{33}}\,$, by simplifying to a point where there is no more linear term, and then substituting $y=x^2$. It took many steps and was quite messy.

Is there some elegant way to solve it?

Comment: Where did you find this task? Did you doublecheck your solutions? Does this equation belong to an active contest?

Comment: To add some "math culture" to the answers by Alex K and Hanno, equations in the variable $x + \frac{1}{x}$ are called [reciprocal equations](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22reciprocal+equation%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1800,cd_max:1899) (also called *recurring equations*, mostly before the late 1800s), and they used to be a standard topic in higher level school algebra texts (1800s; began being phased out by the 1920s or so) and theory of equations texts (a standard undergraduate course up to roughly the late 1950s or so). **(continued)**

Comment: For positive integer values of $n$ it can be shown that $x^n + \frac{1}{x^n}$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ in the variable $x + \frac{1}{x}$ (and hence, positive integer powers of $x^n + \frac{1}{x^n}$ are also polynomials in the variable $x + \frac{1}{x}).$ For example, by expanding $(x + \frac{1}{x})^n$ for $n = 2, \, 3, \, 4$ you'll find that $x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2} = (x + \frac{1}{x})^2 - 2$ and $x^3 + \frac{1}{x^3} = (x + \frac{1}{x})^3 - 3(x + \frac{1}{x})$ and $x^4 + \frac{1}{x^4} = (x + \frac{1}{x})^4 - 4(x + \frac{1}{x})^2 + 2.$

Answer (score 3):

I think your answer is a little off -- as it's always complex.

Observe that $(x\pm\tfrac 1x)^2=x^2\pm2+\tfrac 1{x^2}$ so $(x-\tfrac 1x)^2= (x+\tfrac 1x)^2-4$.

Thus, if we set $u=(x+\tfrac 1x)^2$ your equation is $u(u-4)+2u-2024=0$. The solutions are $u=1 \pm \sqrt{2025}=\{46,-44\}$.

Now we have $x+\tfrac 1x=\pm \sqrt{46}$:$$
x=\frac{\sqrt{46} \pm \sqrt{42}}{2},\frac{-\sqrt{46} \pm \sqrt{42}}{2}
$$

Answer (score 1):

How lucky to get the equation presented in this form, this allows us to fairly quickly determine all its solutions. Not sure if it's elegant, but surely it is effective.

Two observations to start with:
$\,(1)\,$ If $x$ is a solution, then $x\neq 0,$ and $\,-x\,$ and $\,\raise{.1em}{\pm}\,\dfrac{1}x\,$ are also solutions.
$(2)\,$ The first summand of the equation would yield the terms $x^4$ and $x^{-4}$, having the highest and the lowest degree overall respectively. Transformation into a polynomial would thus result in an 8th order equation, and we'd expect 8 roots in total.

Using the identities
$$x^2-\frac{1}{x^2}\:=\: \left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)\left(x-\frac1x\right)
\quad\text{and}\quad\left(x-\frac1x\right)^2 +2 \:=\: \left(x +\frac1x\right)^2 -2$$
the given equation is turned into
$$\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^2 \left[\left(x +\frac1x\right)^2 -2\,\right] \;=\; 2024 = 45^2-1 \\[4ex]
\quad\implies\quad
\left[\frac14\left(x +\frac1x\right)^2 -\frac{46}4\,\right] \left[\frac14\left(x +\frac1x\right)^2 +\frac{44}4\,\right] \;=\; 0$$

Consider the function $x\mapsto\frac12\left(x +\frac1x\right):\mathbb C\backslash\{0\}\to\mathbb C$. For each range value $a\in\mathbb C$ there are two pre-images $x_\pm$, except for $a=\pm 1$. This follows from resolving
$$\frac12\left(x +\frac1x\right)\:=\: a \quad\implies\; x_\pm\:=\: a \pm \sqrt{a^2-1}
\quad\text{and }\; x_+\cdot x_- =1\,.$$
When restricted to the real domain, then the function maps
$\,\mathbb R\backslash\{0\}\twoheadrightarrow(-\infty, -1]\cup [1,\infty)\,$.

Applying this to the factored equation yields
$$\begin{align}
a\quad & \qquad\text{solutions}\\[1ex]
\frac12\sqrt{46} &\qquad \frac12\sqrt{46}\pm\frac12\sqrt{42} \\[1ex]
-\frac12\sqrt{46} &\qquad -\frac12\sqrt{46}\pm\frac12\sqrt{42} \\[1ex]
i\sqrt{11} &\qquad \left(\sqrt{11}\pm\sqrt{12}\,\right)i\\[1ex]
-i\sqrt{11} &\qquad -\left(\sqrt{11}\pm\sqrt{12}\,\right)i
\end{align}$$
The non-real solutions are purely imaginary.